# Truncate a string (to a specific bytes size)

Tags: c#, .net, string, byte, event-log

The [EventLog.WriteEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzwc042w(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not accept strigs exceding 32766 / 31839 **bytes**...

I would like to know how to truncate a string to the specific number of **bytes**.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Log(string message)
{
    const int MaxLogMessageLenght = 32766;

    string logMessage = message;
    var unicodeByteCount = 
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(logMessage);
    var asciiByteCount = 
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(logMessage);

    if (unicodeByteCount >= MaxLogMessageLenght)
    {
        // ????
        // Truncate the string to fit the WriteEntry length
        // logMessage = message.Substring(0, MaxLogMessageLenght - 5) + "...";
    }
    EventLog.WriteEntry(LogSource, logMessage, EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

Comment: `ASCIIEncoding.Unicode` seems a little weird... o.O

Comment: What is wrong with *Substring* ?

Comment: What was the problem with the line you commented out: `message.Substring(...`?

Comment: I need the lenght in **BYTES**, not in chars!

Comment: Then use loop instead of a single *if*

Comment: Does someone thing that "This question does not appear to be about programming defined in the help center"?

Comment: @Serge No closing reason is: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers*

Comment: I didn't say that this code does not work, you have the code, you have the question and specific concrete problem...

Comment: @Serge No **You** have the problem :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson what is weird with AsciiEncoding? Do you know other way to get the lenght in bytes?

Comment: @EZI, you did't read attentively the question before reporting it...

Comment: @Serge It just looks weird to ask an ASCII encoding for a Unicode encoding, that's all.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I don't know what kind if text I will have in log... perhaps some "Texte spécifique comme ça"... ask Microsoft why... ;)

Comment: @Serge You would normally just put `Encoding.Unicode` rather than `ASCIIEncoding.Unicode`

Comment: Oh, sorry, Is a question to Microsoft, not to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

```
const int MaxLogMessageLength = 31839 ;

int n = Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(message);

if (n > MaxLogMessageLength)
{
    message = message.Substring(0, MaxLogMessageLength/2); // Most UTF16 chars are 2 bytes.

    while (Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(message) > MaxLogMessageLength)
        message = message.Substring(0, message.Length-1);
}
```

It's unlikely that the `while` loop will have to do any iterations except for certain languages. If it does, it won't be very efficient.

An initial guess at the required string length is to take the max length divided by two, since most UTF16 characters are encoded into two bytes. Some may take more than two bytes, in which case the message will still be too long, so we have to remove chars from the end until it's short enough.

You could make that more efficient if it was an issue.

Comment: Thanks. As my log language is French, so perhaps is worth trying...

Comment: French does not contain any extended Unicode characters, so it should be pretty efficient, and if you are guaranteed that the message doesn't contain any non-Western (or non-Latin) characters you could probably remove the `while` loop, since it will never do anything.

Comment: So, the maximum length in chars will be some `16 000`, if I'll have a string containing 32000 chars I will do 16000 iterations in the while loop... even in English chars...

Comment: @Serge No, if you have a string containing 32000 chars in French or English, the line `message = message.Substring(0, MaxLogMessageLength/2)` will cut it down to ~16000 chars in one step, and the `while` loop won't be entered, so it will be efficient.